Checking request requirements in PHP Symfony: Do I have to use services? (OOP vs Services in Symfony)
I'm working on my second Symfony project and trying to follow best practices. I've switched from static methods to services for improved readability and potential performance gains. For instance, I have a ResponseService that generates JsonResponse objects from database data. This was handled by a static function in my first project: Responses::getJsonResponse($entityManager, [...])  -->  $responseService->getResponse([...])
My question is:  Should everything requiring autowired arguments and frequent use become a service?
For example, I have a RequirementsCheck class that verifies user permissions, mandatory form data, etc. Here's an example controller method:
#[Route('/ajax/matches/start/', name: 'app_ajax_match_start', methods: ["GET"])]
public function app_ajax_match_start(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): JsonResponse|Response
{
  $req = RequirementsCheck::create($requestStack, $entityManager, permissions: [Permission::EDIT_RESULTS], required_types: ["matches" => "array_int"], data_fields: $_GET);
  if(!$req->isAllowed()) return $req->getResponse();
  // [...]
}

As you can see, I directly inject $requestStack and $entityManager. However, creating a service for RequirementsCheck might improve readability and potentially performance. Still, I feel an object-oriented approach might be more suitable.
What are your thoughts? Is there a universally better solution?
PS: Let me know if there's something I can improve in this post. I'm still quite new and might not have followed all guidelines to the best question.
Edit: Here's the current RequirementsCheck class

Yes your RequirementsCheck should be a service. Services are OOP as well so you might want to review what OOP is. Using the RequestStack in a controller action is very unusual. Normally just Request is all you need. Might want to review that as well. Finally if many of your actions call your requirements checker then you might want to look into kernel request listeners.

@Cerad The difference here would be, that on one side the RequirementsCheck would only be initiated once (As a service), while on the other side in my current solution each request gets it's own instance. Of course in both examples the checker is initialized, but only in one of them it is really an object related to one specific request. Services are of course also OOP, but I think you get what I wanted to say by comparing them.

Edit: The requestStack changes with every request. I might have misunderstood services a bit. Something like EntityManagerInterface IS NOT initialized each time a route is triggered, right? But what if you try to autowire the requestStack to the RequirementsCheckService, then we would need a new instance for each request, since the requestStack changes. My other theory right now would be that we CAN'T autowire the requestStack, but would need to pass it when checking a request. $requirementsCheck->check($requestStack, [...])

This may not be exactly regarding to your question, but I suggest you take a look at Voters, that are the native solution to handling Authorization problems. I think that dividing the logic of validation request data and authorization are two different tasks and should be handled as such. For example: In a voter, you may specify the conditions, when the user can perform the action. Then, using a Validator (also a symfony component) you can validate the request against constraints to ensure that the data is correct.

Yes you can autowire the RequestStack into your checker and then pull the current request from it when you need it. Thus avoiding the need to always pass it as an argument. You can do the same with the entity manager. Though to be honest that fact that you are also passing $_GET as an argument makes me think you don't understand the request object. Never say never but using super-globals in Symfony is extremely rare.  But keep plinking away. Eventually things will start to make sense.


Should everything requiring autowired arguments and frequent use become a service?

Very interesting question! Yes! And it exactly works as you ask for, this is in the Symfony documentation:

Your application is full of useful objects: a "Mailer" object might help you send emails while another object might help you save things to the database. Almost everything that your app "does" is actually done by one of these objects. And each time you install a new bundle, you get access to even more!
In Symfony, these useful objects are called services[...]

(from: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)
This should also give you the hint that you should also look for re-using existing services instead of writing (entirely) your own.
